# Convert Hashmap Java code to Objective C

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c

I want to convert the following Android java code snippet into Objective C. I have no idea how to do it. Anyone?

```
public HashMap <String, String> keyInfo = new HashMap<String, String>();
Set<String> primaryKeys = null;
primaryKeys = keyInfo.keySet();
```

Comment: This is not android specific (it's pure `java`) and I would say it's quite fundamental code. So, what have you done? Don't expect other to do your job!

Comment: I cannot seem to find an equal method to keySet() in objective C. I'm very new to iOS development. So it's hard for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *keyInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSArray *primaryKeys = [keyInfo allKeys];
```